# Moving schema to another database

Tags: sql-server

I have to move an schema from one database to a new database to keep a centralized schema into the same server. The problem is that I already have many stored procedures that use some of these tables from the schema that I need to move.

Is there any workaround to do this and change all the objects that use this tables to be able to pointed to the new database? Can I use synonyms or link server?

I'm working on SQL Server 2008 R2
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep; synonyms are the way to go (stole this example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx):

```
USE tempdb;
GO
-- Create a synonym for the Product table in AdventureWorks2012.
CREATE SYNONYM MyProduct
FOR AdventureWorks2012.Production.Product;
GO

-- Query the Product table by using the synonym.
USE tempdb;
GO
SELECT ProductID, Name 
FROM MyProduct
WHERE ProductID < 5;
GO
```

You could pretty easily generate synonym statements by searching the sys.tables view and identifying the tables which belong to the schema you want to move.